# Can Spinlock, Semaphore, Atomic Variables, KIFIFO and RCU used in high-speed / high-volume concurrency control situation?

Tags: concurrency, linux-device-driver

Can Spinlock, Semaphore, Atomic Variables, Circular Buffer, KIFIFO and RCU used in high-speed / high-volume concurrency control situation? 
These material are including in device drivers in order to understand more.

Comment: Sorry, please reframe your question and provide details in your questions body. This makes no sense (2me).

Comment: This is too broad and conceptual for StackOverflow.

Comment: I thought maybe someone in stackoverflow know about them. I would like to wait a little more,maybe someone know it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be used in high-speed/high-volume concurrency control situation.